# SQL query group by and select the maximum absolute value

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max, absolute

"Table1" structure is as shown below:

[source table table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dImx7.jpg)

```
Player_NAME ||  Player_NUMBER  ||   Client_name ||  Client_country  || Player_country||    Rating   

GERALD  || A1234    || BENFIELD || IND ||   IND ||  76            
GERALD   ||A6578    || ROTFIELD ||  USA || USA ||   64   
KUMAR   || P1234    || LFV  || ARG  || ARG ||   -24  
KUMAR   || P5678    ||JEURASIN ||   ARG ||  TUR ||-32  
KUMAR   || P0101    ||ARGENIA   ||ARG   ||POL   ||-16  
ANDREW  ||R1234 ||  GENMAD  || GER  || GER ||   23
```

I need to select the records from above table “Table1” and copy them to “Table2”.
I need to select the player record from table1  which satisfy the below conditions : 
If   a player has multiple client_names or multiple client_country,  then select the record which has the maximum value of rating . If it is negavie, then take the absolute value of that value. i.e if the rating is -10 and -34, then take the absolute value which is greatest. i. e by taking absolute value  it is 10,34 and 34 is greatest one.
For ex: Kumar has 3 diff client names or 3 diff client_country ,so for kumar the record with rating 32 should be selected ,after taking the absolute value of it.
Below is the expected output:

```
    Player_NAME ||  Player_NUMBER   ||Client_name ||    Client_country  ||Player_country||  Rating    

GERALD  || A1234    || BENFIELD||   IND||   IND||   76    
KUMAR   || P5678    || JEURASIN ||ARG   ||TUR ||    -32     
ANDREW  || R1234    || GENMAD   ||GER   ||GER   || 23
```

[destination table-'table2'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2FUw.jpg)

Comment: What's your DBMS? Does it support `ROW_NUMBER`?

Comment: i use Ms  sql server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
    (
        Player_Name,
        Player_Number,
        Cliet_Name,
        Client_country,
        Player_country,
        Rating
    )
            SELECT
                Player_Name,
                Player_Number,
                Cliet_Name,
                Client_country,
                Player_country,
                MAX(ABS(Rating)) OVER (PARTITION BY player_Name ORDER BY Cliet_Name,
            Client_country) as Rating
            FROM
                table1
```

Comment: I guess, it will give incorrect result. Because of grouping by Player_Name and Player_Number, it will return all records.

Comment: @Jacobian Updated my query.. Hopefully this will provide correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this query will work:

```
select
max(abs(Rating))
from  Table1
group by Player_NAME
```

To insert data into Table2, you can do it like so:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (
    Player_Name,
    Player_Number,
    Cliet_Name,
    Client_country,
    Player_country,
    Rating
)
SELECT
    t1.Player_Name,
    t1.Player_Number,
    t1.Cliet_Name,
    t1.Client_country,
    t1.Player_country,
    t1.Rating
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        Player_NAME,
        MAX(ABS(Rating)) as Rating
    FROM  Table1
    GROUP BY Player_NAME
) t2 ON t2.Player_NAME = t1.Player_NAME AND ABS(t1.Rating) = t2.Rating
```

Comment: i just dont need one column, i want all the columns to copied to table2. above code will take only the rating .

Comment: USE `INSERT INTO Table2(Rating, ...) SELECT max(abs(Rating)) AS Rating, ... FROM Table1`

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports *Analytical Function* you can utilize ROW_NUMBER:

```
select ...  -- all columns but rn
from
 (
   select ...  -- all columns
      ,row_number() 
       over (partition by player_name
             order by abs(Rating) desc as rn
   from table1
 ) as dt
where rn = 1;
```

Otherwise use a Correlated Subquery:

```
select *
from table1 as t1
where abs(rating) = 
 ( select max(abs(rating))
   from table1 as t2
   where t1.player_name = t2.player_name
 )
```

If you got multiple rows with the same `max(abs(rating))` #1. will select one of them randomly, but #2 will select all.